# Unable to Parse string using Hive Regex Serde

Tags: regex, hive, bigdata, regex-group, hive-serde

I am trying to parse a string which is :

> "297","298","Y","","299"

using Regexp serder but i am unable to do so.
The Table definition i have created is :

```
create external table test.test1
(a string,
b string,
c string,
d string)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
with serdeproperties ("input.regex" = "\"\"|\"([^\"]+)\"")
```

the regex used in the serde properties looks promising in the regexp test websites but i am getting exception while trying to read the table kindly help me out in this.
I know that this can be easily done using csv serde but i am trying to figure out a bigger part of the problem for which i have to use the regexp serde 
Thanks

Comment: Read also this article: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Using-Regular-Expressions-to-Extract-Fields-for-Hive-Tables/ta-p/247562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the regex it should be capturing group per column.
Your data contains 5 columns and table 4, you want to skip one column, right?

For example this regex will work: `with serdeproperties ('input.regex' = '^"(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)",.*?,"(.*?)"$')`

You can easily check without creating table, like this:

```
select regexp_replace('"297","298","Y","","299"','^"(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)",.*?,"(.*?)"$','$1|$2|$3|$4');
OK
_c0
297|298|Y|299

select regexp_replace('"297","298","Y","this column is skipped","299"','^"(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)",.*?,"(.*?)"$','$1|$2|$3|$4');
OK
_c0
297|298|Y|299
```